# 220V Induction Heater Electrical Connection

Tags: voltage, electrical, wiring

I'm hoping to get an induction heater for my condo, but the heater requires 1 hot, 1 neutral, and 1 ground. I believe that's a European electrical setup, so how would this get connected in the United States? As far as I know, there's no way to do a single phase 220v line, at least not in a residential setting. I have heard of transformers that may do something to that effect? But, I already have a nema 14-50R plug in my garage and I'm hoping there's a way I could safely power the heater with that. Does anyone know of any solutions? For instance, could I just attach two hots and the ground to the heater, cap off the neutral, and just plug into the outlet?

The induction heater: https://ussolid.com/u-s-solid-15-kw-high-frequency-induction-heater-30-80-khz-16-1-turns-ratio-220v-or-110v.html

Jsyk: I do not have any kind of background in electrical engineering, so please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: First make you have enough power left over for that amount of extra use.  It would be best to use a heater made for the US that is listed by one of the testing labs(UL, CSA).  A European electrical device might not meet code.  Some European devices can use neutral as a second hot for 220v, but that is a device by device choice.  This does not seem to be an area/room heater, more like an manufacturing type heater to heat up pieces.  Is this what you want?

Comment: Where is the need for a 15 kW, high frequency, industrial induction heater in a condo? Here's a demo video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ipZ4vdivbU.

Comment: @crip659 yes. I'd be using it instead of a propane forge since my complex and insurance doesn't allow open flames.

Comment: @vu2nan ^^^^^^^

Comment: Your insurance would probably not look kindly on running this dangerous, un-listed equipment in your home either.

Comment: I can't help but wonder how it provides 15kW of output from 7kW of input.

Comment: Hi Richsticks, Got it, thanks.

Comment: @KMJ - I suppose 'Max. Inductive Power: 15 KW' refers to KVA. Considering 'Max. Input Power: 7 KW', the power factor would be 0.47.

Answer (score 3):

It's Chinese wiring.  Which is similar to Europe.

There's an importer that has an office in Cleveland called JoyFay International. Their mainline items are plush animals, but they have another of sideline "fake brands".  One of them is US Solid - sounds American, sounds solid, sounds *supported*... but it's the exact opposite.  It's an imported item from some random company behind the Red Curtain and parts and support will be nonexistent.

[image]

This building is way too small to be a manufacturer. Either it's a warehouse, or just an office that relies on Amazon Fulfillment. Also note the *local delivery* vans and trucks pushed into the back, and complete lack of semitrailers at the docks at 9-5 on a workday when the satellite photo was taken (note half-full parking lots of nearby manufacturers, but only 4 cars in their lot).  Probably not even a warehouse, then... they seem to be integrated into Amazon's platform, as is typical.

Anyway, the problem with answering your question is that this equipment is almost always snuck in around consumer safety rules, which means it is not UL-Listed (or certified by a recognized agency to conform to UL White Book safety standards).  And that means it probably doesn't have an accurate or reliable *data nameplate* that would answer your question about power requirements. We are reduced to guessing.

But it does seem to say something about 7kW line supply, which would require about a 37A breaker.  Loads which are actually 5800-9600 watts are appropriate for a NEMA 14-50 receptacle.

Comment: It's "interesting" that the website says "This machine cannot be used with a plug. A wire will be necessary to connect the machine to power source directly ..." while the PDF manual says "Turn off and unplug the machine when making any adjustments ..." (while never saying anything about cord or hardwire, circuit size, etc). Stay away.

Comment: Yeah, probably will. I haven't been able to find anything similar and "American" made. I haven't been looking long though. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: @nobody that's what happens when UL doesn't approve the item or the instructions.

Comment: @Richsticks What you really want is a listing from a NRTL such as UL, CSA or ETL.  (never CE or CCC, those are fake).  China is perfectly capable of building quality, ask any Mac owner.

Answer (score 0):

The info about the unit says it can be 220V OR 110V.

That said, the unit may not conform to North American standards.

Comment: True, I dont know why it was downvoted, correcting it

Comment: Technically true that the website says that but totally fails to address the lack of UL listing, safety issues, practicalities of running a 7kW load on 120V, etc. Not useful to the sort of person asking a question like this and not deserving of upvotes.

Comment: OP's Questions: " I believe that's a European electrical setup, so how would this get connected in the United States?   And; " Does anyone know of any solutions? "   The fact that it can be powered by 110V  answers the questions.  Any other fodder about convertors or transformers is moot.